# Can't scroll textarea placeholder text in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, textarea

I've created a simple `textarea` element with placeholder text. When in **firefox**, I can't scroll down the entire text (it gets cut off), whereas in **chrome** it works fine.

```
<textarea placeholder="here is some text, I would like to scroll down and read it entirely...">
```

## see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hp0ywtsd/4/)

couldn't find any docs about placeholders issues in firefox

Comment: Did you try adding height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1239595).